# Problem With AND condition

Tags: c#-2.0

Code Below:

```
if(var != "" && var.startswith("somestring"))
 { do something }
```

This code is troubling; as far as my understanding var != "" will be evaluated first and then if true then the other part will be evaluated but this concept is not working seems :)

If var is having a value null then I am getting an "nullreferrence" exception; which means 
var != null is not getting evaluated.

Please Help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: You're comparing var to "", not to null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, there is a difference between a null string and an empty string. You have to check for all 3 cases, in fact, C# contains a helper method for just this case:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(var) && var.StartsWith("somestring"))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Testing for empty is redundant, and it can be incorrect in some cases, if the condition on the write said `!var.StartsWith` instead of `var.StartsWith`...

Comment: Although I agree with you, I'm of the opinion that the OP wants to lump the null and empty string conditions together, which is quite common. So I'm going to leave the code as is.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant `null` instead of `""`:

```
if (var != null && var.startswith("somestring"))
{ do something }
```

---

P.S.: `var` is a reserved keyword in later versions of C#.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the empty check isn't even necessary

Comment: `var` is actually a *contextual* keyword; it's legal to do `int var = 0;` in C# 3 / 4.

Comment: @Ani: Oh, totally forgot; thanks!

Comment: @Ani cool, didn't know that, but still just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

var != "" is not the same as var != null.

Comment: Thank You every one for your spontanious response. Yes, I got it; if I check for var!= null instead var!= ""; I am cool then. I think for me the best bet would be using the String.IsNullOrEmpty method. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are getting data from a TextBox and using .NET 4.0, I would suggest using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace to check for only white space characters as well as null and empty.

Answer (score 0):

"" is a valid `string` - it just happens to have length 0. But it is not `null`!

To check for a `null`, write `var != null`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is ever a possibility that your variable will be null, you need to check if its null or not before you attempt to do any kind of processing (even a simple comparison), or you will get this "nullreference" exception.

```
if(var != null){
//gitter done
}
```